# Firebase find keyword from my database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my firebase data.
I want to use the word which typed in in the last page(b),to find if there have similar data in my database or not.
Like I typed tt, and it will show that all titles that contained tt(e.g.tt123 tt456)
How should I do?

[image]

```
public class List extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mRef;
    private static  final String TAG = "List";
    private ListView list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
I take the keywords from here.

        //Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        //String b = bundle.getString("text");
        //Query query = mRef.child("users").orderByChild("username").startAt(b);

        DatabaseReference reference_contacts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("商品");
        //Query query = mRef.equalTo(b);
        reference_contacts.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                adapter.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                    adapter.add(ds.child("titles").getValue().toString());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),ProductPage.class);
                String a = ""+position;
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("num",a);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to use the word which typed in in the last page(b),to find if there have similar data in my database or not.
Like I typed tt, and it will show that all titles that contained tt(e.g.tt123 tt456)
How should I do?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What were the results?

Comment: I don't know what to do,so I have not do anything yet.